# Confusion about this, global object and global scope

Tags: javascript, object, scope, this

Reading Doug's "Javascript: the goods parts" in the chapter 4 about functions talk about "The method invocation pattern" and "The function invocation pattern" (page 28).

> When a function is stored as a property of an object, we call it a
>   method. When a method is invoked, *this* is bound to that object.

That is clear. Then in the same page:

> When a function is not the property of an object, then it is invoked
>   as a function:
>   var sum = add(3, 4); // sum is 7
>   When a function is
>   invoked with this pattern, *this* is bound to the global object. This
>   was a mistake in the design of the language.

My questions:

- 1.- With "this is bound to the global object" means that *this* is bound to the global scope?
- 2.- With "This was a mistake in the design of the language" means that *this* should be follow the same rules as the methods follow? ie, bound *this* to himself?

Thanks.-

**EDIT**: Both answers given are very instructive and well documented. Thanks to all participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Yes

2 - If you keep reading, right after that he describes an example that makes it a 'mistake in the design of the language'.

```
var myObject = {
  value: 1
};

myObject.double = function() {
  var that = this;

  var helper = function() {
    alert('in helper, this.value = ' + this.value + ' and that.value = ' + that.value);
    that.value = that.value + that.value;
  }

  helper();
};

myObject.double();
alert('after doubling, myObject.value = ' + myObject.value);
```

The alert will show that using 'this' in the function that is a property of the object will not work.  If the global object (likely window) had a `.value`, then that would be seen in that alert.

Comment: Isn't that a seperate issue, namely that `this` isn't lexically scoped?

Comment: @rosscj2533 I supposed that someone it could tell me "continue reading" RTFM, right? LOL. Yes, I have study this example and your last statement let me understand much better, Thanks!

Comment: @NomikOS - no problem, when I was reading through the book, I added that alert in there to illustrate it, so thought it could help you too. @delnan - in this context, this does illustrate the issue. Isn't the fact that `this` isn't lexically scoped the issue?

Comment: @rosscj2533 Hi rosscj, can you please update the snippet showed in this answer to work properly? [http://jsfiddle.net/VkfnS/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/VkfnS/1/).

Comment: @NomikOS - updated answer, also working example here - http://jsfiddle.net/yCH26/1/

Answer (score 1):

`window` is the global object in JavaScript. If you define a function like this:

```
function myFunc() {
}
```

It will be bound to the global object, `window` and using `this` inside the function will refer to the `window` object. If you define a function as a property of an object, such as:

```
var obj = {
   myMethod: function() {
   }
};
```

And use `this`, it will refer to the object.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/williamvanr/qBXF8/

Comment: AFAIK, functions aren't bound based on how they are created but based on how they are called. With `myFunc.call(obj)` and `var fn = obj.myMethod; fn()`, `this` is not as you claimed but the other way around.

Comment: @delnan I think that understand you. That's why Doug talks about 4 distinct invocation patterns, Am i right?

Comment: delnan is saying that if you assign `obj.myMethod` to a variable defined in the global scope, the context will change to `window`, which is true. You can also change the context with `call` on a function: `myFunc.call( obj )` will change the context to `obj`. [http://jsfiddle.net/williamvanr/qBXF8/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/williamvanr/qBXF8/1/)

Comment: @william-van-rensselaer WOW. +1 Yes, I am reading about the `call` method and all this is making much sense. Thanks!